Playwright test.use multiple parameters issue with arrays
My test fixture implements ways to create single or multiple advertisers via API. When I use a single request array in test.use(), all works fine and the log reveals that the request is passed as an array. But all becomes abnormal when I add 2 requests array in test.use()，only the first request was sent out as a non-array object.
Here is my codes.
withAdmin.ts (the test fixtures)
// Fixtures useful for signed-in users.
import {
  AdvertiserRequest,
  AdvertiserResponse,
} from "@utils/models/advertiser";
import { organizations, users, advertisers } from "./manageObject";

type TestFixtures = {
  ...
  advertiserDetails: AdvertiserRequest[];
  advertiser: AdvertiserResponse;
  advertisers: AdvertiserResponse[];
};

// Playwright test extended with page fixture logging the user in and additional fixtures requiring a user.
export const test = base.extend<TestFixtures>({
  ...
  advertiserDetails: [new AdvertiserRequest()],
  advertiser: async ({ advertisers }, use) => {
    await use(advertisers[0]);
  },
  advertisers: async ({ appApiContext, advertiserDetails }, use) => {
    console.log("advertisersDetails:", advertiserDetails);
    await advertisers(appApiContext, advertiserDetails, use);
  },
});

manageObject.ts
import { expect } from "@playwright/test";
import {
  AdvertiserRequest,
  AdvertiserResponse,
} from "@utils/models/advertiser";

export const advertisers = async (
  appApiContext,
  advertisersDetails: AdvertiserRequest[],
  use: (r: AdvertiserResponse[]) => Promise<void>
) => {
  const results: AdvertiserResponse[] = [];
  // Fixture advertisers can be overwrite to create more than one advertiser
  // Default fixture has just one object
  for (const advertiserDetails of advertisersDetails) {
    const createAdvertiser = await appApiContext.post("./advertisers/", {
      data: {
        name: advertiserDetails.name,
        category: advertiserDetails.category,
        website: advertiserDetails.website,
        is_active: advertiserDetails.isActive,
      },
    });

    await expect(createAdvertiser).toBeOK();
    const responseJSONcreatedAdvertiser = await createAdvertiser.json();
    const id = responseJSONcreatedAdvertiser.id;
    const organization = responseJSONcreatedAdvertiser.organization;
    const live_campaign_count =
      responseJSONcreatedAdvertiser.live_campaign_count;

    results.push(
      new AdvertiserResponse(
        advertiserDetails,
        id,
        organization,
        live_campaign_count
      )
    );
  }

  await use(results);

  // Delete created advertisers
  for (const advertiser of results) {
    const responseDelete = await appApiContext.delete(
      `./advertisers/${advertiser.id}/`
    );
    expect(responseDelete.status()).toBe(204);
  }
};

AdvertiserRequest:
/**
 * Advertiser request data, created for fixture purposes.
 *
 * Fields in this class are to be used as POST request data to create an advertiser.
 * There are default values for the class fields defined in the constructor.
 * When no values are provided, an object with these defaults is created.
 */
export class AdvertiserRequest {
  name: string;
  category: string;
  website: string;
  isActive: boolean;

  constructor(
    name = "AD_E2E_1",
    category = "Apparel & Accessories",
    website = "https://www.ad-e2e-1.com",
    isActive = true
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.category = category;
    this.website = website;
    this.isActive = isActive;
  }
}

/**
 * Information of an advertiser.
 * Extends AdvertiserRequest class by adding some fields.
 */
export class AdvertiserResponse extends AdvertiserRequest {
  id: number;
  organization: number;
  live_campaign_count: number;

  /**
   * Extend Advertiser object base with ID of created Advertoser object.
   * @param base - The Advertiser object base.
   * @param id - The ID obtained from response of created Advertiser object.
   * @param organization - The organization ID obtained from response of created Advertiser object.
   * @param live_campaign_count - The number of live campaigns of created Advertiser object.
   */
  constructor(
    base: AdvertiserRequest,
    id: number,
    organization: number,
    live_campaign_count: number
  ) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, base);
    this.id = id;
    this.organization = organization;
    this.live_campaign_count = live_campaign_count;
  }
}

test
test.describe("Test with 2 advertisers", () => {
  test.use({
    advertiserDetails: [
      new AdvertiserRequest(
        "AD_E2E_1",
        "Video Gaming",
        "https://www.test-blackmith.com",
        false
      ),
      new AdvertiserRequest(
        "AD_E2E_2",
        "Apparel & Accessories",
        "https://www.test-underdog.com",
        true
      ),
    ],
  });

  test("Check sorting of Advertiser table", async ({
    page,
    advertiserDetails,
    ...

I print the advertiserDetails defined in test.use()
Passed advertiserDetails: AdvertiserRequest {
  name: 'AD_E2E_1',
  category: 'Video Gaming',
  website: 'https://www.test-blackmith.com',
  isActive: false
}

If I specify a request array in test fixture advertisers, all seems normal. I assume the problem is about test.use().
advertisers: async ({ appApiContext, advertiserDetails }, use) => {
    console.log("advertisersDetails:", advertiserDetails);
    await advertisers(appApiContext, advertiserDetails, use);
  },

